# How to monitor hash rate over time to diagnose issues

Tags: miner-configuration, hashpower, scrypt

Running a Scrypt mining rig using GPUs.

Want to know if there's a way to monitor your hash rate over time.

Pool stats arent that reliable from what I understand.

CG Watcher, does a decent job, but its chart is limited in range.

Any other software of pool that would offer more data / reporting ?